# Get array values based on bitmask in PHP

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, array-map

I have a 32-bit integer used for bitmask and an array with 32 values. How to get only those values from the array which indexes correspond to the positions of the non-zero bits in the bitmask?

For example let say that the bitmask is 49152 which is 1100000000000000 in binary. Therefore I have to take the values of elements with indexes 14 and 15 from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some PHP code for you, but please note it is pretty inefficient.  I have used this algorithm because:

1. It is explicit and uses words rather than mathematical tricks to get the job done, and
2. Works in situations where you can't assume an underlying implementation of 2s complement, but still want to 'think' that way. <sub><sup>(try 'storing' bitmasks in PHP and thinking they will work in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number))</sup></sub>

Please read the comments and implement @Paebbels solution. The difference in performance is almost 7x, so really only use this if it will not be used very often.

It utilizes `base_convert` to convert the base 10 integer to base 2, splits the string into a character array, reverses the array and then iterates over it looking for 1s.

```
$mask = 49152; // 0xC000

// Find which positions in the mask contain a '1'
$bitArray = array_reverse(str_split(base_convert($mask, 10, 2)));

foreach($bitArray as $k => $v) {
    if($v) {
        echo $k . " is a one\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

> 14 is a one
>
> 15 is a one

As a function:

```
function extractElements($mask, array $input) 
{
    $output = array();
    $bitArray = array_reverse(str_split(base_convert($mask, 10, 2)));

    foreach($bitArray as $k => $v) {
        if($v && isset($input[$k])) {
            $output[] = $input[$k];
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

$mask = 76; // 0x4C
$input = [
    'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight'
];

print_r(extractElements($mask, $input));
```

Output:

> Array
>   (
>      [0] => Three
>      [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) => Four
>      [2] => Seven
>   )

Comment: Sorry, but this solution is consuming masses of memory and CPU cycles for a job of simple bit shifts and bit-compares.

Comment: _Masses of memory_? Not too bad for a 32-bit integer mask. Unless you have real-time requirements (.. in PHP ..) or you are repeatedly calling this, then this solution is appropriate. Otherwise, I'm sure people will find your answer helpful.

Comment: My solution: 3 words á 4 bytes = 12 bytes {m, j, i}, it has no call instructions. -- Your solution converts mask from int to string; uses a base conversion based on double values (string to double, base convert, to string conversion); after that a string operation (str_split) is used and finally a string reverse operation. These are just the initial coasts ... In every iteration you are accessing a hash list and calling a isset function for a simple bit compare. Your code uses 35 call instructions.  Memory: each char of a intermediate string is stored in 2 bytes (UTF-16) => 64 bytes.

Comment: I'm not saying one should reduce memory and runtime at all coast, but converting int -> string -> double -> string is more expensive than using a mask integer and 2 count variables.

Comment: Updated to make the caveats to this approach more explicit. Hopefully @Nikola Obreshkov will return and rethink.

Comment: I have implemented this solution and it works solid. I have to admit that the second answer seems more efficient from algorithmic point of view. For anyone interested the practical usage was to tag the treated teeth in a dental image.

Comment: You could remove the `foreach` loop and instead use this line: `return array_intersect_key($input, array_filter($bitArray));` to get exactly the same array: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7d9a706c34797d1b0a5d5a74ccd2f969b227b0e

Answer (score 6):

You will need to loop in 32 steps over your mask and test it for '1', if this bit is set, you can copy the element to your resulting array.

Pseudo code:

```
m = 0x00000001
j = 0
for i in 0 to 31 loop
  if ((mask & m) = m) then   // bit is set in mask
    result(j++) := input(i)
  end if
  m := m << 1     // shift left by 1 or multiply by 2
end loop
```

Comment: How can you criticize Jeff Lambert's real **PHP** code when all you offer is _pseudocode_ which doesn't address the posted question ?

Comment: As Jeff noted, my proposed algorithm (which he implemented) is 7x faster!

Comment: This isn't even PHP. #JustSaying

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a function that fits your needs, and in additional:

- can handle smaller or bigger data type
- saving the values and not only the indexes

---

```
function extractMask($mask, &$idxs, &$values) {
    for($i = 0, $valueToCompare = 1; $valueToCompare <= $mask; $i++, $valueToCompare <<= 1) {
        if ($mask & $valueToCompare){ 
            $idxs[] = $i;
            $values[] = $valueToCompare;
        }
    }
}

// usage:
extractMask(49152, $idxs, $values);

// results:
var_dump($idxs);
var_dump($values);
```

For impression, here is a JS snippet:

```js
function extractMask(mask) {
  var result = {idxs: [], values: []};
  for(i = 0, valueToCompare = 1; valueToCompare <= mask; i++, valueToCompare <<= 1) {
    if (mask & valueToCompare){ 
      result.idxs.push(i);
      result.values.push(valueToCompare);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//====================== UI ==========================
var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
anchor.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var result = extractMask(input.value);
  console.log(result);
});
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var result = extractMask(input.value);
    console.log(result);
  }
});
//====================================================
```

```html
<input value="49152" />
<a href="#">calculate</a>
```